# Proof of $\pi^e$ and $e^\pi$ Being Irrational

Tags: proof-verification, exponential-function, irrational-numbers, pi

By contradiction, if $\pi^e$ were rational, then we could write $\pi^e=\frac{a}{b}$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{I}^+$ and $b\neq0$.  So: 
$$\begin{align}
\\ \pi^e&=\frac{a}{b}
\\ e\ln(\pi)&=\ln(a)-\ln(b)
\\ e\int_1^\pi \frac{1}{t}dt&=\int_1^a \frac{1}{t}dt-\int_1^b \frac{1}{t}dt
\\ e&=\frac{\int_b^a \frac{1}{t}dt}{\int_1^\pi \frac{1}{t}dt}
\end{align}$$
But we know that $e$ is irrational.  So if $p=\int_b^a \frac{1}{t}dt$ and $q=\int_1^\pi \frac{1}{t}dt$, there can't exist an $a$ and $b$ such that $\frac{p}{q}=e$.  Therefore by contradiction, $\pi^e$ must be irrational.  The proof is similar for $e^\pi$.
**Q.E.D.**

Does this work, or did I assume something I couldn't?

Comment: Your integrals are not integers, which is required here...

Comment: Whether $\pi^e$ is rational or not is a well-known open problem. It turns out that $e^\pi$ is irrational, but the proof uses a rather difficult theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This proof is not correct.  The fact that $e$ is irrational means that you can't write $e=\frac{p}{q}$ **where $p$ and $q$ are both integers**.  Your $p$ and $q$ are not integers (at least not obviously so), so you don't get a contradiction.  Every number $x$ can be written as a fraction $\frac{p}{q}$ for *some* $p$ and $q$ (for instance, $x=\frac{x}{1}$); this does not mean every number is rational.

Comment: Indeed $q\approx1.145$.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument also proves that $e^{\ln2}$ is not rational.