# Can $\pi$ be expressed as $\ln a - \ln b$ and if so can $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: number-theory, logarithms, irrational-numbers, pi

Can the number $\pi$ be expressed as $\ln a - \ln b$ and if so can $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: $\ln a-\ln b=\ln a/b$. All arguments are rational, so the first expression is overkill.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1853814/proof-of-pie-and-e-pi-being-irrational?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

if so we would get $$\pi=\ln\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$$ and from here we get
$$e^\pi=\frac{a}{b}$$ this is impossible if $a,b$ are rationals

Comment: Are you sure it's known that $e^\pi$ is irrational? (It is indeed highly likely ...). A search shows that $e + \pi$ and $e\pi$ are not known (though related) Reference please.

Comment: @EthanBolker: I had to look this one up too. [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%27s_constant)